# Change On-Screen-Keyboard language layout in windows 10 iot

Tags: c#, windows, windows-10-iot-core, windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

Microsoft reveals **OSK(on screen keyboard)** for windows 10 iot core Creator update *(build 15063)* , it works good but i faced a problem!    I want use it in other language layout , for example i need an on screen keyboard with Persian Layout that have Persian alphabet.

*Does anyone have an idea to solve this ?*

Comment: There's no way to change the keyboard layout for another process (i.e., `osk.exe`). If you want your system to use the Persian layout, then you could change the system globally to a Persian localization.

Comment: @CodyGray i use this line of code to set culture to fa-IR but my osk not changed to Persian layout.
 `CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("fa-IR"); 
      CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;`

Answer (score 1):

Working on version v.10.0.17661.1001.

To switch between languages, press and hold on the &123 key.

Note: This keyboard takes the place of the split keyboard layout.